# Xamarin Cross Platform - Login/Register

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am trying to implement identity login into my cross-platform app. I have created Azure SQL database and configured API services in my app. Everything is working fine, I can register / login users. However, I want to check if the user loggedin or not and display dialog boxes (you successfully registered/logged in, or password does not match/wrong etc.). And if it is success, I want to navigate user to mainpage of the app. Could you please advise me how to achieve this? Thank you for your support.

Here is what have done so far:

**apiservices.cs**

```
public class ApiServices {
    public async Task RegisterUserAsync(string email, string password, string confirmPassword) {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var success = false;
        var model = new RegisterBindingModel {
            Email = email, Password = password, ConfirmPassword = confirmPassword
        };
        try {
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
            HttpContent content = new StringContent(json);
            content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
            if (email != null || password != null) {
                success = true;
                Acr.UserDialogs.UserDialogs.Instance.ShowSuccess(string.Format("You are now signed-in as {0}.", email));
                var response = await client.PostAsync(Constants.BaseApiAddress + "api/Account/Register", content);
                Debug.WriteLine(response);
                Debug.WriteLine(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                Debug.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Acr.UserDialogs.UserDialogs.Instance.ShowError(string.Format("Authentication Failed: {0}", ex.Message));
        }
    }
}
```

**registerViewModel.cs**

```
public class RegisterViewModel {
    public string Email {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string Password {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string ConfirmPassword {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public ICommand RegisterCommand {
        get {
            return new Command(async() => {
                ApiServices apiServices = new ApiServices();
                await apiServices.RegisterUserAsync(Email, Password, ConfirmPassword);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**loginViewModel.cs**

```
public class LoginViewModel {
        public string Email {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public string Password {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public ICommand LoginCommand {
            get {
                return new Command(async() => {
                    ApiServices apiServices = new ApiServices();
                    await apiServices.LoginUserAsync(Email, Password);
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what specific problem are you having?  You appear to know how to call your API methods, and to display a dialog?  What specifically do you not understand?

Comment: I do not understand how to check user logged in/register as well as show dialog box to user for return ("you are registered", "password doesn't match", "wrong email format" etc.)

Comment: your login/register functions should return a bool, which you would need to store (use Settings, like suggested below.  You can easily show dialogs with  the built in DisplayAlert or using the Acr Dialogs package you're already using

Answer (score 0):

Install [Xam.Plugins.Settings](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugins.Settings/).

It will add a helper class called Settings

In this class you should add:

```
private const string IsLoginKey = "login_key";
private static readonly bool IsLoginDefault = false;

//Then adding this property
public static bool IsLogin
{
    get
    {
        return AppSettings.GetValueOrDefault(IsLoginKey, IsLoginDefault);
    }
    set
    {
        AppSettings.AddOrUpdateValue(IsLoginKey, value);
    }
}
```

Then in your `App.xaml.cs` file like this:

```
using YourProjectNameSpace.Helper

.....

if (Settings.IsLoggedIn)
{
    MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
}
else
{
    MainPage.DisplayAlert("Your Title","You Message","OK");
    //Or navigate to Login page, like this:  
    //MainPage = new NavigationPage(new LoginPage());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, it gave me some ideas but this is not what I am looking for. And the logic of your code is not complete. It will not loop in both conditions.